# Forgot Pokemon Go Player ID

Tags: pokemon-go

I can remember my user name, but without the player ID I can't request a new password.

It won't allow me to set up a completely new account with the same email either (which I tried out of frustration)

Please help

Comment: I have created an account via google, so I am not 100% sure, but it is common for any web service to send an email to you when you sign up. That email contains a conformation link, but usually things like an id too. Have you scanned your email for emails coming from niantic?

Comment: if you know the email, can you not just use the lost password link to have it reset?

Answer (score 5):

Ah, okay. I may have just found the answer for myself. Maybe it will help others who are trying to log in. Your user name may not be the same as the name you use on Pokemon Go or other apps they have here. So when you are trying to reset your information you may assume that your user name is the same as the user name that you use on any app or something that you use your trainer account login to get into, but it is not necessarily the same. If your password reset is not working, try this link first: https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-username

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon Go accounts set up through the Pokemon Trainer Club can be password-reset if you can supply just *one* of either the Username, Player ID, or your date-of-birth. You do not need to know your Player ID if you have one of the other two.